# Check a password in Javascript with a regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

i've got an expression checking whether there is at least one number, one lowercase and one uppercase letter and at least 6 characters in a password string.
please see my example:

```
var myPwd = 'test-123H';
console.log('password to check: ' + myPwd); 
//at least one number, one lowercase and one uppercase letter and at least six characters
var re = /(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,}/;
var validPassword = re.test(myPwd);
console.log(validPassword);
```

unfortunatly i can't manage it to achieve two more conditions: the password should be checked against a maximum length of 15 characters and there should be at least 2 numbers instead of one. could anyone tell me the trick?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can modify your regex to this:

```
var re = /^(?=(\D*\d){2})(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[A-Z]).{6,15}$/;
```

- `(?=(\D*\d){2})` => will make sure there are at least 2 digits
- `.{6,15}` makes sure there are min 6 and max 15 character
- `^ and $` are line start and line end anchors

**Visual Description:**

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: @anubhava please give an ex. pwd that matches the regexp.

Comment: @anubhava I guess "A34.+Bce2" is a valid password. But the rule you have given doesn't conform it as a password. So please suggest a password that this regexp is supposed to support.

Comment: OP has provided an example passord `test-123H` that will match this regex. Even your `A34.+Bce2` will also match.

Comment: So, how can i achieve that the condition "there must be 2 digits in it" is being changed to "there must be 2 digits or special characters in it"

i tried something like this:
    var re = /^(?=(\D*\d | !@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?){2})(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[A-Z]).{6,15}$/;

but there's a problem in the expression

Comment: What characters do you want to be included in special characters?

Comment: generally all of them:
!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?]*$/

obviously the or conditon must be written with an pipe as OR and in brackets?

latest try:
    var pwRegEx = /^(?=(\D*\d|(?=.*[^!+@#$%])){2})(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[A-Z]).{6,15}$/;

Comment: OK thanks I am on mobile now. I will provide an answer to this once I get back to my computer.

Comment: OK, that would be brilliant; until now i'm not able to manage it

Comment: Try this regex: `/^(?=(.*?[-\d!@#$%^&*()_+=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?]){2})(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[A-Z]).{6,15}$/;`

Comment: Unfortunatly no..the following password string should match because there's an uppercase letter as well as a lowercase and 2 digits. a string like 'Test@b1' should also match because 1 number and 1 special character is alright, too

    var newPwd = 'Test-12';
    console.log('password to check: ' + newPwd);
    var pwRegEx = /^(?=(.*?[-\d!@#$%^&*()_+=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?]){2})(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[A-Z]).{6,‌​15}$/; 
    var isValidPassword = pwRegEx.test(newPwd);
    console.log('test result: ' + isValidPassword);

Comment: Let me test it and post a comment here. Give me few minutes.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43430/discussion-between-michbeck-and-anubhava)